# When is it necessary to unsubscribe in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, observable, subscription

I've gone through articles and videos and I understand how to unsubscribe, but I'm still having trouble understanding **when** I need to unsubscribe.  Here is some simplified code I have in my project.  I am subscribing to an observable in a service I have and I am also subscribing to data from my Firebase Firestore I've created for my project.

matches.component.ts

```
constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore, public authService: AuthService) {

}

subscription: Subscription | undefined
authSubscription: Subscription | undefined

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authSubscription = this.authService.adminInfo.subscribe(info => {
      console.log(info)
    })

    this.subscription = this.afs.collectionGroup('matches', ref => ref.orderBy('date')).snapshotChanges().subscribe(async (resp) => {
      for (const item of resp) {
        console.log(item)
      }
    });
  }
```

auth.service.ts

```
constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore, public authService: AuthService) {

}

participantSub: Subscription | undefined
private adminInfoSub = new BehaviorSubject({uid: ""})
adminInfo = this.adminInfoSub.asObservable();

makeData() { //Gets called when the user logs in
    this.participantSub = this.afs.collectionGroup('participants').snapshotChanges().subscribe(info => {
        const adminInfo = {
            displayName: info.displayName,
            uid: info.uid,
            tournaments: info.tournaments
        }
        this.adminInfoSub.next(adminInfo)
    })
}
```

The matches component is a tab that you can navigate to and away from in the app and the auth service is just a regular Angular service.  So my question is, do I need to unsubscribe from any of these subscriptions and why or why not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular/RxJS When should I unsubscribe from \`Subscription\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription)

Answer (score 2):

You need to unsubscribe to **any** observable that doesn't complete.

Unless `complete()` is called on a subject or an error is thrown, it doesn't complete.

So in your case, if you don't unsubscribe, you'll get yourself a nice memory leak !

Answer (score 0):

You can check this answer, it has detailed explanation of when and what kind of observables you need to unsubscribe.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41177163/7488155)

Looking at your code you should unsubscribe to both observables in your component manually.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!